# How to add auto add in input button and click submit in ReactJs in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, iframe

I want to load iFrame and in that there's an input button to enter a name, and then start a call. (Basically a meet link)

What I am looking for is a way where I can pass the name from the JS function or something similar and then it clicks the start meeting button.

What I am trying to do is start the meeting without the user's input of name or anything.

this is the code sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-fog-hybzpx?file=/src/App.js

Even If I am unable to click to button at least I want to pass the name and can I disable the input button after passing the name? Such that the user doesn't change the name?

Comment: $(".field")[0].value = "testValue"

Comment: @SyedArsalanHussain I didn't get it

Comment: Try this in your running browser it will change the value 
I can not get the full screen otherwise I would have gotten the id or class of button to start meeting and made it click from JS